# Sort strings by key value - Golang

Tags: string, sorting, go

I have the following string blob in Go:

```
  AWS_FIREHOSE_US_WEST_2_ENDPOINT: https://foobar.firehose.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  BOT_NAME: mybot
  DEV_MODE: false
  GITHUB_APP_ID: 1234
  GITHUB_INSTALLATION_ID: 1234
  GITHUB_ORG_NAME: myorg
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_HOST: foo.bar
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_PORT: 80
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_PROTO: http
  TZ: UTC
  _APP_NAME: myapp
  _BUILD_ID: 12345
  _DEPLOYMENT_ID: dev--foo.d53
  _DEPLOY_ENV: dev
  _OTEL_COLLECTOR_URL: tcp://localhost:4317
  _POD_ACCOUNT: 12345
  _POD_ID: a6127c9c-2be8-4078-8c00-132d29fbecfc
  _POD_REGION: us-west-1
  _POD_SHORTNAME: us-west-1-dev-default
  _TEAM_OWNER: eng-infra
  _TRACING_ENABLED: false
  force_restart: 2024-01-02T19:00:59Z
  GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  fofofofofofofofofofofofofofoofofofofofofofofofoffof
  barbabaabababababababababababababababababaababababa
  batbababtbabttbtbabtbtabtbtbtbtbtbabtbtbbtbtbtbttbt
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

This is a single string in Golang, separated by "\n", so please notice, it's not sorted by the `key: value` pair. I need to sort it out by the primary key, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

I've tried the following method:

```
// sortLines sorts the lines in a blob of text.
func sortLines(blob string) string {
    var sorted sort.StringSlice
    sorted = strings.Split(blob, "\n")
    sorted.Sort()
    return strings.Join(sorted, "\n")
}
```

Please notice trying to sort by line won't work due to the fact the `GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY:` contains multiple lines.

Comment: Split the string according to the file’s syntax, not by line. What is the syntax?

Comment: @CeriseLimón the syntax is as described in the string blob example: `<key>: <value>`

Comment: Describe the syntax for a value.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: The syntax for a value is: ASCIIArmorValue | OrdinaryValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Revised to handle all forms of ASCII Armor.

---

Your string is not a blob. It has a well-defined structure. It contains an ASCII Armor value:

```
GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
fofofofofofofofofofofofofofoofofofofofofofofofoffof
barbabaabababababababababababababababababaababababa
batbababtbabttbtbabtbtabtbtbtbtbtbabtbtbbtbtbtbttbt
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

---

> [IETF RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880.html)
>
> [6.2.  Forming ASCII
> Armor](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880#section-6.2)
>
> [6.6.  Example of an ASCII Armored
> Message](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4880#section-6.6)
>
> ```
>    -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
>    Version: OpenPrivacy 0.99add ASCII Armor example to test data
>
>    yDgBO22WxBHv7O8X7O/jygAEzol56iUKiXmV+XmpCtmpqQUKiQrFqclFqUDBovzS
>    vBSFjNSiVHsuAA==
>    =njUN
>    -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
> ```

---

A case insensitive sort (insert ASCII Armor example into test data):

```
  AWS_FIREHOSE_US_WEST_2_ENDPOINT: https://foobar.firehose.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
  BOT_NAME: mybot
  DEV_MODE: false
  force_restart: 2024-01-02T19:00:59Z
  GITHUB_APP_ID: 1234
  GITHUB_INSTALLATION_ID: 1234
  GITHUB_ORG_NAME: myorg
  GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY: -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  fofofofofofofofofofofofofofoofofofofofofofofofoffof
  barbabaabababababababababababababababababaababababa
  batbababtbabttbtbabtbtabtbtbtbtbtbabtbtbbtbtbtbttbt
  -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
  IETF_RFC4880_ASCII_ARMOR_EXAMPLE: -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
  Version: OpenPrivacy 0.99

  yDgBO22WxBHv7O8X7O/jygAEzol56iUKiXmV+XmpCtmpqQUKiQrFqclFqUDBovzS
  vBSFjNSiVHsuAA==
  =njUN
  -----END PGP MESSAGE-----
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_HOST: foo.bar
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_PORT: 80
  SERVICE_WHO_IS_WHO_DEFAULT_PROTO: http
  TZ: UTC
  _APP_NAME: myapp
  _BUILD_ID: 12345
  _DEPLOYMENT_ID: dev--foo.d53
  _DEPLOY_ENV: dev
  _OTEL_COLLECTOR_URL: tcp://localhost:4317
  _POD_ACCOUNT: 12345
  _POD_ID: a6127c9c-2be8-4078-8c00-132d29fbecfc
  _POD_REGION: us-west-1
  _POD_SHORTNAME: us-west-1-dev-default
  _TEAM_OWNER: eng-infra
  _TRACING_ENABLED: false
```

https://go.dev/play/p/B3x_AbAvZHs

```
func sortConfig(config string) (string, error) {
    type KL struct {
        key, lines string
    }

    var kls []KL
    scnr := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(config))
    inArmor := false // ASCII Armor (IETF RFC4880)
    for scnr.Scan() {
        line := scnr.Text() + "\n"

        if inArmor {
            kls[len(kls)-1].lines += line
            armor := strings.TrimSpace(line)
            inArmor = !strings.HasPrefix(armor, "-----END ") ||
                !strings.HasSuffix(armor, "-----")
            continue
        }

        if len(strings.TrimSpace(line)) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        key, value, pair := strings.Cut(line, ":")
        if !pair {
            key, value = "", key
        }

        if pair {
            armor := strings.TrimSpace(value)
            inArmor = strings.HasPrefix(armor, "-----BEGIN ") &&
                strings.HasSuffix(armor, "-----")
        }

        key = strings.TrimSpace(key)
        key = strings.ToUpper(key) // case insensitive
        kls = append(kls, KL{key: key, lines: line})
    }
    if err := scnr.Err(); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    slices.SortStableFunc(kls, func(a, b KL) int {
        return cmp.Compare(a.key, b.key)
    })

    var b strings.Builder
    b.Grow(len(config))
    for _, kl := range kls {
        b.WriteString(kl.lines)
    }
    return b.String(), nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The current code isn’t working due to untrimmed spaces: they affect the sorting keys.

Wouldn’t you like to trim the RSA key before sorting the other keys? If you suspect an RSA key of always being added to the end of input string.

Hope this should help:

```
func SortLines(blob string) string {
    gpkSignature := "GITHUB_PRIVATE_KEY:" //  github RSA  key
    gpkIndex := strings.Index(blob, gpkSignature)
    return sortLines(blob[:gpkIndex], blob[gpkIndex:])
}

func sortLines(blob, gpk string) string {
    var sorted sort.StringSlice
    sorted = strings.Split(blob, "\n")
    sorted = append(sorted, gpk)
    for i := range sorted {
        sorted[i] = strings.TrimSpace(sorted[i])
    }
    sorted.Sort()
    return strings.Join(sorted, "\n")
}
```